# Record limited incoming call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have phone numbers in twilio account, but I want to record just limited incoming calls for each number, how can I do that? by configuration or by REST API?

Comment: What are you doing with those numbers? What TwiML do they receive when they are called?

Comment: I have one number per trunk, and for example, if the number receives 5 calls I need to record the 5th one then turn off the trunk recording, and for the next 5 calls, I need to record the 10th one and so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no way to configure the trunk to act like this, but if you keep count of when you want recording on or off then you can [update whether the Trunk is recording using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/api/trunks#action-update).